# Other CSSs being picked up

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, twitter-bootstrap, vb.net-2010

i'm having an issue trying to implement bootstrap into our ASP.NET Web Forms (VB) project. We have decided to implement this change one page at a time so we are needing to run 2 master pages at the same time. One master page w/ bootstrap, the other will have our original CSS settings. Eventually all pages will be converted to the bootstrap master page, once they are checked to make sure they are displaying correctly.

The issue... is when I run a page w/ the bootstrap  master page, some how, the original CSS is being picked up (by IIS, or something) and is messing everything up. The original CSS is NOT in the bootstrap master page. Moreover, when I rename the original CSS page it still being picked up. I need to know how I can either place the original CSS so it doesn't affect the bootstrap master page, or some how make it so its not being picked up.

I feel like this may be a duplicate question (as i can't believe i'm the only one with this issue), but I couldn't find it any place which might be because i'm not sure how to word the question.

Please help if you can!

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is happening both ways. So my bootstrap CSS is being auto-magically imported into my original master page.... and my original CSS is being auto-magically  imported into my bootstrap master page. EVEN THOU NEITHER HAVE THE REFERENCE.

Also, i tried to add the reference to each myself, in order of preference, and something, somewhere even over-rides that.

**EDIT 2**

yes, i removed the default theme in the web.config. I have even put the themes in in the @PAGE tag it still bring in the other CSSs.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="App_Master/bootCerulean.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" title="Home" StylesheetTheme="bootCerulean" Theme="bootCerulean" %>
```

This is new... I have 4 child folders in my "App_Themes" folder, and the page that is connected to one, IS NOT brining in the other CSSs. The only differences in the pages & was the @Page Theme attribute. I added it (above), and still no go...

**EDIT 3**

when i REMOVE ALL REFERENCES to ANY CSS in my master page, and add the @Page Theme attribute, it only brings in items for the theme i'm using. This is an ok solution for now.

But i want to know WHY/HOW this auto import of themes work. Also there isn't a "THEME" setting on a master page level, or is there?

That would solve the issue right there!

Comment: It may be due to conflicts in the way css is defined between bootstrap, and your original css.

Comment: do you have html,body in both css files? also look for same called divs/classes in both css files. they will always conflict eachother then.

Comment: @Karthirkr - bootstrap & the original are on SEPARATE master pages, so ... i would think it shouldn't matter. Neither are referenced in other master page.

Comment: Just wondering if your browser may have cached the old CSS file and be referencing it still? Maybe a long shot, but try clearing your cache or viewing the pages in a different browser.

Comment: @KeesSonnema yes. There are naturally going to be the same elements in each, mainly ul, li, etc. I do not have html in either CSS, and body is only in the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Are master pages hard-coded or set dynamically (in your content page/s) or in web.config (setting)? Do you use themes (folder or web.config)?

Comment: @ralph.m i tried that... still seeing the original CSS show up in the bootstrap master page.

Comment: @EdSF - master pages are hard-coded (if i'm understanding ur question). We use themes folders. I have one folder for the original CSS and other data. And one for me bootstrap CSS. When I look at the bootstrap pages source code thru the browser I see the reference to the original CSS, but in the master page, or the page I'm looking at (thru the asp content control) doesn't have the original referenced.

Comment: @JoshuaHarris - did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: @chuex Yes... I did... several times... :( i was really hopeful that was it.

Comment: Can you please post the markup for your MasterPages.  Also, do your MasterPages inherit from `Page` or are they inheriting from any sort of custom base page class?

Comment: Are you using themes? ["When you put a .css file in the theme folder, the style sheet is applied automatically..."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @whoshotjr - I think... I am using theme FOLDERs. Not sure if that is the same thing. I have App_Themes, then different folders. One for bootstrap, the other for my original. THE CSSs are separated thou. I will try to move the CSSs out and see what happens...

Comment: @MikeC - I will post them in a few. Trying to clean them up. Lots of code that isn't needed and can be confusing...

Comment: _"I am using them folders...App_Themes"_ : this should be the culprit which is why I was asking about it. Check your web.config settings to see which theme (folder) is being applied.

Comment: @EdSF The "default" folder WAS named in the web.config under the <pages> tag, but i removed it...


'<pages theme="Default">'

Comment: @MikeC - can you explain what you mean by inherit from PAGE ? 

Are you talking about in the MASTER page tag? 

Right now I have "<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="bootCerulean.master.vb" Inherits="App_Master_bootCerulean"  %>" the Inherits is the code behind.


Also, im not sure how posting code will help... Any time i put ANY CSS in ANY child app_themes folder it is picked up on all themes. Regardless... there has to be a setting some place that i'm missing.

Comment: @JoshuaHarris Have you looked at the link that whoshotjr posted?  Sounds like that's probably EXACTLY the problem.  Don't put your CSS in the `~/App_Themes' folder (or subfolders).  Just put it in a normal file folder like '/css'.

Comment: If you're using the App_Themes folder then you're using themes. CSS in here will be applied automatically.

Comment: @whoshotjr - this isn't always true ... read my update 2.... I have a child folder in my App_Themes folder that is ONLY pulling in files for the correct theme (it does have the @ page theme attribute). So the other CSSs from other folders are NOT being auto-magically applied.